# how to exclude specific pages form wordpress search results?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show only today's events and the next events in Worpdress search results for every posts with category "events". This is my code and it doesn't work.

```
function du_filter_search($query){
   if ( ! is_admin() && is_category( 'events' ) && $query->is_main_query() && is_search() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'endDate' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'endDate',
                'value'   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'compare' => '>=',                
                'type'    => 'DATETIME',
            )
        ) );
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'du_filter_search' );
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: thank you for your response. The events that have ended are still appearing in the search results. I want to show only today's events and the next events.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  I think you need to update the `meta_query` to be:

```
function du_filter_search($query){
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'endDate' );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
      array(
        'key'     => 'endDate',
        'value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
        'compare' => '>=',                
        'type'    => 'DATE',
      )
    ));
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'du_filter_search' );
```

Using `DATE` in-place of `DATETIME` and remove the `H:i:s` from from todays date.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did your suggestions but the results remained the same.

I got a reference from google:


`add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_exclude_filter' );

function my_search_exclude_filter( $query ) {

  if ( ! $query->is_admin && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 3, 11, 234, 553 ) );

  }

}`

But if using the codes above, I have to set the posts ID manually.

Comment: Does this query need to happen on search or the category archive or both?

Comment: only on search results

Comment: OK, then I don't think you need the `&& is_category( 'events' )` check.  I updated my original answer to remove it.

Comment: Also updated the `is_search()` for `$query->is_search()`.

Comment: THANK YOU! the search filter for posts in the "event" category is working. But I got new problem, the posts on another category that contains same keyword as "events" category also doesn't appear in search results. I want the filter only affects posts in the "event" category. Do you have any suggestions?